# How to filter a SAM file by a bed file?

Tags: sam, samtools, pysam

I have a large BAM file and I want to filter it by just what's defined in a bed file, and write it to a new file.

Is it possible to do this with samtools, and if so, how? Is there a better tool I could use to do this?

Comment: Did you look at the options for samtools view?

Comment: ´samtools view` has filtering options for BED files as reference. Type `samtools view` and check available flags.

Comment: Hi, i.think your question needs more specific details

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to the helpful comments I figured it out:

```
samtools view -b -h -L bedfile.bed originalbam.bam > newbam.bam
```

-b = Output as bam file
-h = include header
-L = only output alignments overlapping the input BED file

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this with [`bedtools intersect`](https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/intersect.html):

```sh
bedtools intersect -abam input.bam -b bedfile.bed > output.bam
```

This should be identical to the `samtools view` answer. One further feature though is you can output all reads that **don't** overlap with the regions in `bedfile.bed` by adding the `-v` flag.